# Replace values by running maximum values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the format

```
id  time  a  b
01    01  1  0
01    02  0  1
01    03  0  0
02    01  0  0
02    02  1  0
02    03  1  1
02    04  0  0
```

So now, the output should be

```
id  time  a  b
01    01  1  0
01    02  1  1
01    03  1  1
02    01  0  0
02    02  1  0
02    03  1  1
02    04  1  1
```

Here, I am grouping by `id` and for each `id`, the df is sorted by `time`. Now, I want to replace the values in `a` and `b` by the maximum value seen thus far. I guess I can apply a rolling max on each group but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like a cumulative maximum? :)
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html

You'd have to call it for every group, but it beats a for-loop, which you'd also have to do for every group.

Comment: I did `df['a'] = df.groupby('id')['a'].apply(pd.cummax)` but this gives an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cummax'`. Not really sure how to use cummax! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The columns a and b can be replaced by their cummulative max value with the [cummax function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html), like acdr suggested.

Here is the one-liner:

```
df[["a","b"]] = df.groupby("id").cummax()[["a","b"]]
```

Output:

```
    id time a   b
0   1   1   1   0
1   1   2   1   1
2   1   3   1   1
3   2   1   0   0
4   2   2   1   0
5   2   3   1   1
6   2   4   1   1
```